# Cómo puedo eliminar un error de Web Scraping en R

Tags: r, scraping

Estoy intentando scrapear en R para realizar una data frame sobre la Presidencia del Consejo de Ministros. Un CSS ya corrió, referido al nombre de los funcionarios, el que sería una columna de mis datos. Sin embargo, el otro -la que contendría los cargos- no corre debido a que R no reconoce el símbolo "/" y me lo señala como error. El SCC es el siguiente: h3.font-light.mb-6.w-10/12.text-base.leading-tight

Ejecuto el siguiente comando:

```
css_Cargos="h3.font-light.mb-6.w-10/12.text-base.leading-tight"
Cargos_html <- html_nodes(pcm_fun,css_Cargos)
Cargos_texto <- html_text(Cargos_html)
head(Cargos_texto)
```

Pero aparece este error:

```
Error in tokenize(css) : Unexpected character '/' found at position 24
```

¿Cómo podría solucionar este error para obtener ambas columnas con la información pertinente?

Comment: ¿probaste escapeando la barra con la doble barra `//`? es decir `"h3.font-light.mb-6.w-10//12.text-base.leading-tight"`

Comment: Comparte la página web para ayudarte